# How to create a package of models in Django

Tags: python, django

Having a quite large `models.py` file (which contains several models), I'm trying to refactor, with one model per file.

I'm therefore trying to create a `models` package, with the following structure:

- `app/models/__init__.py`
- `app/models/first_model.py`
- `app/models/second_model.py`

Unfortunately, I cannot get Django lazy reference mechanism to work well, i.e.:

```
first_model = models.ForeignKey('app.FirstModel')
```

returns the error that Django cannot find the model.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work, make sure that in __init__.py you are importing all the models from first_model.py and second_model.py.

```
from .first_model import FirstModel
from .second_model import SecondModel
```

EDIT: If you want to retrieve the models as 'app_label.model_name', then you will have to import them in __init__.py, otherwise you can try the following:

Use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model

Or you can use ContentTypes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#methods-on-contenttype-instances

Comment: Thank you, but this is not really the issue here. The problem is that Django cannot find them using lazy referencing.

Answer (score 3):

The presence of `__init__.py` tells Python to consider it as a Package, but in order to let Django find your models for Migration and find it well, you should import all your models stuff in `__init__.py`

Keep the structure like it was:

```
app/models/__init__.py
app/models/first_model.py
app/models/second_model.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .first_models import *
from .second_models import *
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Cookbook](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookSplitModelsToFiles) there is an example using only the name of the class (model) and not the app part:

```
first_model = models.ForeignKey('FirstModel')
```